# Infinite Scroll Flickering on iOS webkit browser when setting scrollTop explicitly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scrolltop

I have a strange problem and it is hard to explain. Still I will go ahead and try it. What is happening is I have an infinite scroll logic, where I load more content when user scrolls to the bottom of the page and if the no of DOM elements increases beyond a certain limit, I remove an equal chunk of DOM element from the top, to keep the no of DOM elements in the page constant and to keep the memory in check. Now, when I add new elements at the bottom and remove old elements from the top, I have to set the scrollTop position of the scrollable  element (the parent container) explicitly just to maintain the user's scroll position. I am using Jquery's scrollTop() method call to set the scroll position at the moment. As soon as I update the scroll position with a call to scrollTop() the page flickers and I can see a white patch for a brief moment on iOS devices. This happens even with the native Javacript scrollTop property. The issue is seen only on iOS webkit browsers(both webviews and browsers on devices as well as simulator) and I am not seeing the same issue on Android webviews. Even on desktop browsers, it runs just fine including Safari.

The code that I am writing is meant to be a bi-directional infinite scrolling but for this question I am only posting the code for downward scrolling.

Here is the code snippet -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> 
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                background: #fff;
            }
            #holder {
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }


            ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            ul li {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 20px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #9a9a9a;
                background: #e5e5e4;
            }
            .androidFix {
              overflow: hidden !important;
              overflow-y: hidden !important;
              overflow-x: hidden !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="holder">
            <div id="container">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Script goes here -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars.js"></script>

        <!-- Sample data -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = [{slno: '1', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '2', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '3', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '4', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '5', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '6', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '7', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '8', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '9', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'},
                        {slno: '10', amount: '250', name: 'DAG Account', date: '16/07/2014'}];
        </script>

        <!-- Handlebars template -->
        <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#each data}}
                <li>
                     <div>
                        <span><b>sl no {{slno}}</b></span>
                        <span>{{amount}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>{{name}}</span>
                        <span>{{date}}</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </script>

        <!-- App logic -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var source   = $("#template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var html = template({data: data});
            //console.log(html);

            var holderRef = $("#holder");
            var holderHeight = $("#holder").height();

            var newChunk = $("<ul class='list-chunk' />");
            newChunk.append(html);

            var containerRef = $("#container");

            containerRef.append(newChunk);  //initial data load

            var chunkHeight = $(".list-chunk").height();


            $("#holder").scroll(function() {

                //test for bottom
                var scrollTopVal = this.scrollTop;

                var containerHeight = containerRef.height();

                //console.log('test', scrollTopVal);

                if(scrollTopVal + holderHeight >= containerHeight) {
                    console.log('bottom');

                    var newChunk = $("<ul class='list-chunk' />");
                    newChunk.append(html);

                    containerRef.append(newChunk);

                    //if($("#container").children().size() > 2) {
                    if(containerRef.children().size() > 2) {
                        var viewTop = $("#holder").scrollTop();

                        var oldChunk = containerRef.children().first();
                        var oldChunkHeight = oldChunk.height();
                        console.log(chunkHeight);
                        oldChunk.remove();

                        setScrollTop(viewTop - chunkHeight);  
                    }

                }


                function setScrollTop(amount) {
                    $("#holder").addClass("androidFix").scrollTop(amount).removeClass("androidFix");   //******* - the problem lies here
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may have something to do with iFrame of iOS webViews..

Comment: did you come across something like this?

Comment: Yes, once when we were using scrolling, at that time we use to bring a certain chunks of data from server and feed it to the html page,it got resolved by manipulating the iFrame, I am just guessing yours might be the same issue

Comment: Kindly add more details. I do not have any iFrame in the code nor I am using one.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am experiencing the similar problem (with native page scroll) on iOS browsers, while it's fine on Android.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions / guesses in the order I would try them:

Your androidFix class is also being applied on other systems. Instead of applying a class, change that elements style props directly (element.style.overflowX = "hidden" etc ) only on the system that needs it. Do browser sniffing perhaps. You could apply your scrollTop directly in the same call as well, which would save you having to toggle the class on then off around the scroll setting, and save multiple expensive DOM manipulations.

Scroll events fire a lot, DOM manipulations are very slow, especially mutating the DOM tree. You could set a flag (changingDOM = true) then just return straight away from subsequent calls to the scroll handler, until you're done and set it back to false.

Come to think of it, is this the reason for androidfix? setting scrollTop recursively calls the scroll handler, unless you overflow=hidden? In that case, I would try the latter change first of all.